# Grails Runtime Exception - Value too long for column "PHOTO BINARY(255)

Tags: grails

I am getting the captioned exception when tying to load jpeg files (between 3 and 8 KB) into a column defined as `byte[]`, using Grails 2.2.3 - here's the error:

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Value too long for column "PHOTO BINARY(255) ... SQL statement: update profile set col1=?, ..., photo=?, ..., coln=? where id=?`

This was working in Grails 1.3.7, using the org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver, but is now always failing. Should I be defining the variable differently? If so as what?

I tried changing all the `byte[] photo` code to `byte[] photo = new byte[10000]`, but that did not help at all.

---

I am adding on to the original question in response to the answers I've been given. First of all thank you all. This is the relevant code in DataSource.groovy:

```
environment {
  developement {
    dataSource {
      dbCreate = "update"
      url = "jdbc:h2:file:devDb:MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
    }
  }
}
```

The following file and code is where I thought the image was being loaded from - ImageController.groovy:

```
class PhotoUploadCommand {
  byte[] photo
  //def photo      // tried, makes no diff here
  String userId
  static constraints = { photo(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) }  // added as per suggestions
}
class ImageController {
  def imageService
  def upload = { PhotoUploadCommand puc ->
    def user = User.findByUserId(puc.userId)
    user.profile.photo = puc.photo
    //user.profile.photo = request.getFile('photo')  // also tried - N/G
    redirect(controller: 'user', action: 'profile', id: puc.userId)
}
```

If I comment out all the code beginning with `class ImageController {` and ending with the closing `}` it makes no difference - therefore, I must be wrong and this is NOT where the images are being loaded from. However, there is no other code in this entire application that I can find that directly relates to loading the photo. So it must be scafolding from the Profile.groovy class:

```
class Profile {
  byte[] photo
  //def photo  // tried, but then the element is removed from the template
  String fullName
  String bio
  String homepage
  String email
  String timezone
  String country
  String jabberAddress
  String skin

  static mapping = {
    photo column: 'photo', sqlType: 'VARBINARY(10000)', nullable: 'true'
    //photo(type: 'image')  // also tried
  }

  static constraints = {
    fullName(nullable: true)
    // ... 
    //photo(nullable: true, maxSize: 1024 * 1024)  // also tried
    photo(nullable: true)
    // ... 
  }
```

There is also a UserContoller.class that contains all these same columns and additionally:

```
String userId
String password
String passwordRepeat
```

... and changing `byte[] photo` to `def photo` there does nothing - neither does adding the mappings. Very confusing for a Java programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use constraints to set field size .

```
class MyDomain {
    .....
    byte[] photo

    static constraints = {
        photo(maxSize: 1024 * 1024)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you emilan, but it didn't change - still the same error.

Comment: It works for me ok. Check if dbCreate  = 'create' in DataSource.groovy

Comment: No it is set to update. That's because I want to keep the data from one session to the next.

Comment: Could you check the type of photo in DB, it should be VARBINARY. P.S. you can do it via dbconsole executing select * from information_schema.columns;

Comment: Thank you again emilian. I added a lot of code to my original question ( I was not able to add well formatted code to a comment ). I will try to check the DB type.

Comment: I checked the base directories and recursively all sub-directories of both my Gails1.3.7 and springsource and there are no files, no matter the case, named dbconcole*. If you were thinking of MySql or an external DB I am not using one. I am using the built in h2 DB. Before that, using Grails 1.3.7 I was using the built in hsqldb DB, and it worked using that.

Comment: This article will help to find dbconsole. http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2011/11/h2-database-console-in-grails-2/

Comment: emilan, that makes it clear - I got in and sure enough, the profile.photo is varbinary(255).

Comment: Thank you! As I said I logged in. Then I altered the table profile to change photo to varbinary(10000). Now I can upload the pictures (jpeg files).

Answer (score 4):

You can use either the `constraints` or `mapping` closures to affect the hibernate column type:

**Using constraints**

Grails will examine the `maxSize` or `size` constraints to inform the size of column necessary.

```
static constraints = {
    photo maxSize: 10000
}
```

**Using column definitions**

Grails allows you to specify the sql datatype in the mapping closure. These can be specific to your DB vendor, but covers cases where the constraint hints aren't flexible enough to match your DB schema. e.g. Using postgres bytea columns.

```
static mapping = {
    photo column: 'photo', sqlType: 'VARBINARY(10000)'
}
```

Comment: Thank you codelark. By the way, I also tried doing it the way shown on this site: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-grails06099/ ... `def photo; user.profile.photo = request.getFile('photo')` but that did not work either. I will try what you suggest, but would you happen to know if the syntax would be similar for the org.h2.Driver ?

Comment: codelark, are mapping and constraints mutually exclusive? ... because I am geting very odd errors about other fields that I am not changing. This is one thing that, coming from a Java background, I don't like about Grails ... the errors are very hard to make sense of - at least to me. Pardon me please though, as I am only a beginner. thanks, ~Bill

Comment: This is really bizzar. If I add the mapping, or if I change the type of photo from the "typed" byte[] to just "def", then photo column no longer shows on the gsp for the person's profile where it should. If I don't use the mapping, but put on the constraints size for photo and keep it as a byte[] type, then it appears, but still limits the size to 255.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [type](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html) defintion:

```
static mapping = {
    photo(type:'image')
}
```

It will be automatically mapped to the correct type of the database...

---

Make sure the database schema is set/upgraded properly.

Comment: Thank you matcauthon. However I am not sure how to check what the database scheme is set to. I added a lot of code to my original question ( I was not able to add well formatted code in a comment ).

Comment: If what you meant was the same as what emilan meant; namely, getting into the dbconsole, then that was what I ended up doing - I altered the profile table by modifying the photo column to varbinary(10000). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. I tried about a dozen suggestions from the web--none of them worked.

That is until I changed my `dbCreate` for my development environment in **DataSource.groovy**.  I had it set to "**update**" because I wanted to keep my data.  Then I guessed that the *database columns* couldn't be resized unless the database was recreated.  So I changed it to "**create**", ran grails *run-app*, *shut it down*, then switched it back to "**update**".  I had to re-enter all my data, but the *image upload* worked from that point on.